# post arduino data via ethernet to display into php

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

I have difficulty to post arduino data into php via ethernet shield. I have data from arduino (ambient temperature, devices and so on) and want to store it into mysql databases and display on php web page. So I found someone do it on wireless from github: https://github.com/ericbenwa/POST-Arduino-Data-Wireless/blob/master/arduino_post/arduino_post.ino

So I decided to modify some code from it and do it on my localhost server. but when I run on arduino , it doesn't connect and failed connection. Please Help!

//#include 
    //#include

```
// EDIT: Change the 'ssid' and 'password' to match your network
//char ssid[] = "yournetwork";  // wireless network name
//char password[] = "yourpassword"; // wireless password
//int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
//WiFiClient client;
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x90,0xA2,0xDA,0x0D,0x0D,0xB1};  //Replace with your Ethernet shield MAC
EthernetClient client;
IPAddress ip(198, 100, 130, 65); //ethernet ip address attatched to my ethernet shield

// EDIT: 'Server' address to match your domain
char server[] = "127.0.0.1"; // This could also be 192.168.1.18/~me if you are running a server on your computer on a local network.

// This is the data that will be passed into your POST and matches your mysql column
int yourarduinodata = 999;
String yourdatacolumn = "yourdata=";
String yourdata;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Ethernet.begin(mac,ip);
delay(1000);
Serial.println("connecting...");
postData();
}


// This is the data that will be passed into your POST and matches your mysql column
/*int yourarduinodata = 999;
String yourdatacolumn = "yourdata=";
String yourdata;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  connectWifi();

  // You're connected now, so print out the status
  printWifiStatus();

  postData();
}*/

void loop() {

}

/*void connectWifi() {
  // Attempt to connect to wifi network
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    // Wait 10 seconds for connection
    delay(10000);
  }
}*/

/*void printWifiStatus() {
  // Print the SSID of the network you're attached to
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // Print your WiFi shield's IP address
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // Print the received signal strength
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}*/

// This method makes a HTTP connection to the server and POSTs data
void postData() {
  // Combine yourdatacolumn header (yourdata=) with the data recorded from your arduino
  // (yourarduinodata) and package them into the String yourdata which is what will be
  // sent in your POST request
  yourdata = yourdatacolumn + yourarduinodata;

  // If there's a successful connection, send the HTTP POST request
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connecting...");

    // EDIT: The POST 'URL' to the location of your insert_mysql.php on your web-host
    client.println("POST /data/insert_mysql.php HTTP/1.1");

    // EDIT: 'Host' to match your domain
    client.println("Host:127.0.0.1 ");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(yourdata.length());
    client.println();
    client.println(yourdata); 
  } 
  else {
    // If you couldn't make a connection:
    Serial.println("Connection failed");
    Serial.println("Disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program you show here runs on your device, correct?

The host ip number 127.0.0.1 is a special IP address. It always means "the machine upon which the present program is running."  Accordingly, your arduino code is trying to connect to a web server on the same arduino device, not your server.

You need to use the network IP address of the server machine to which you're connecting. Update this line.

```
 char server[] = "127.0.0.1"
```

I would tell you what to put here, but I have no idea. You have to find out the IP address of your server.

Comment: Yes, it's a sketch run on arduino. Can I run on local server, localhost, that 's why I put it on 127.0.0.1

Comment: I changed the server IP address to my own server address. But the result on serial monitor is "connecting .." forever.